# How to pass Token Key and Token Secret to Alamofire request?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, alamofire

I have Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Token Key and Token Secret to get Data API. like this in postman:

[image]

I must get data my API like in capture postman above. then I have method request with Alamofire like this:

```
    Alamofire.request("https://conversation.8villages.com/1.0/contents/articles?state=published", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            print("test", response.request!)  // original URL request
            print("ini responseny", response.response!) // HTTP URL response
            print("test", response.data!)     // server data
            print("test", response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }
```

So, I don't know how to add or pass my token to in method get. someone help me, please.

I'm using *OAuthSwift* and *Alamofire*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/headers", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: where i pass my token?

Comment: you can pass in headers@fermendkis